# Table for optional parent/child relationship

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key

Assuming we have the following table: Item, Parent, Child and Parent is the parent of child.

The item can either belong to a parent or child and not both.

I have other tables that are similar to Item and they too can belong to either a Parent or Child.

Should I simply just add 2 nullable FK to them?

Can I enforce that either a Parent or Child must exists using the db?

Comment: Is this for mysql or postgres?

Comment: Currently, I'm using postgres.

Comment: See this answer by @Erwin then: [Complex foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021)

Comment: can you describe what you are actually going to store in the database? it may help

Comment: Can an item belong to more than one child / parent, as long as they are not related ?

Answer (score 8):

The solution you outlined is one valid option - assuming that an item can only belong to a single *person* at any given time.

In **PostgreSQL** you can enforce mutual exclusion between the two fk columns with a simple [`CHECK` constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2410):

> either a Parent or Child must exists

... you can add a simple `CHECK` constraint:

```
CHECK (a IS NOT NULL OR b IS NOT NULL)
```

Would demand at least one `NOT NULL` column - but also allow that both `parent_id` *and* `child_id` exist. If you want to disallow that, too, make it:

```
CHECK (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NULL OR b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NULL)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't really work on MySQL though. Would work fine on SQL server or Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the MySQL tag on the question and didn't read through that the asker is using Posgres. 
I Retagged the post

Comment: @druzin: Yeah, this is meant for Postgres, since the OP commented he was using that.